# Изменение поведения кнопок по щелчку Bootstrap, CSS

Tags: css, bootstrap

Есть кнопка:

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
```

Если зажать левой клавишей мыши по кнопке происходит примерно следующее: выделяется кнопка по контуру и прожимается. После самого клика - отжимается. Если быстро кликнуть - то происходит моментальное зажатие и сразу же отжатие кнопки.

Как убрать любые эффекты, которые происходят при нажатии? То есть нужно чтобы она максимум выделялась, а не прожималась и отжималась.

Данный код не решил проблему:

```css
.btn-primary:focus,.btn-primary:active, .btn-primary:hover{
    outline: none; !important;
    box-shadow: none; !important;
}
.btn:focus,.btn:active,.btn:hover{
    outline: none; !important;
    box-shadow: none; !important;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

> update: изменил описание стилей

Возможно что-то излишне, но пока что лишь бы работало.

```
        .btn:focus,
        .btn:active {
            box-shadow: none !important;
        }

        .btn-primary:active,
        .btn-primary:focus {
            box-shadow: none !important;
        }

        .btn-lg:active,
        .btn-lg:focus {
            box-shadow: none !important;
        }
```

Теперь при наведении на кнопку перестал изменяться(затемняться) цвет фона, она лишь подсвечивается по контуру. Но при нажатии этот эффект остался.

> update: с bootstrap buttons благодаря документации разобрался. Остался
>   последний вопрос:

```
<input type="button" name"SomeButton">
```

При нажатии на такую простейшую кнопку есть мерцание. Возможно ли его убрать, чтобы нажатие по кнопке было визуально таким же, как по простейшей ссылке? Без всяких эффектов. По нажатию что-то происходит, но кнопка вообще не меняет свой вид

> update:

В примере у вас именно то что нужно по сути. При наведении на кнопку, нажатии на нее, она такая же, как и зажатая. Т.е. focus, hover, active нужно привести к одному виду - к active.

Берем в спецификации:

```
.btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active, .btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active,
.show > .btn-primary.dropdown-toggle {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #0062cc;
  border-color: #005cbf;
}

.btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active:focus, .btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active:focus,
.show > .btn-primary.dropdown-toggle:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(0, 123, 255, 0.5);
}
```

И, чтобы нигде накосячить, все это реализуем однообразно:

```css
.btn:focus,
.btn:hover,
.btn:active,
.btn:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active,
.btn:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active {
  background-image: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  outline: 0 !important;
}

.btn-primary:focus,
.btn-primary:hover,
.btn-primary:active,
.btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active,
.btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active,
.show>.btn-primary.dropdown-toggle,
.btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active:focus,
.btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active:focus {
  background-color: #0062cc !important;
  border-color: #005cbf !important;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(0, 123, 255, 0.5) !important;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Получаем то, что нужно по сути, но совершенно другой внешний вид зажатой кнопки (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 1) Убираем тень

1. Перед `!important` не должно быть точек с запятой. Уберите их, и ваш код заработает.
2. `outline: 0;` для класса `.btn` Бутстрап добавляет сам. Эту инструкцию от себя можно уже не писать. См. [bootstrap.css](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.css):

```css
.btn:focus, .btn.focus {
    outline: 0;
}
```

3. А тень Бутстрап назначает дважды — и для `.btn`, и для `.btn-primary`:

```css
.btn:focus, .btn.focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(0, 123, 255, 0.25);
}

.btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(0,123,255,.5);
}
```

Поэтому, чтобы убрать тень, надо либо копировать из Бутстрапа строку для `.btn-primary`, либо добавлять `!important`, либо ещё как-нибудь пересиливать Бутстрап [по специфичности](https://specificity.keegan.st/).

Если тень не нужна у всех кнопок на сайте, то инструкция с `!important` выглядит проще и работает жёстче.

Проверьте:

```css
.btn:focus,
.btn:active {
  box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

---

#### 2) Устраняем мерцание для `.btn-primary`

Бутстрап задаёт для `.btn-primary` фон и границу: `background-color: #007bff; border-color: #007bff;`. При наведении мыши делает их темнее: `background-color: #0069d9; border-color: #0062cc;`. При нажатии — ещё темнее: `background-color: #0062cc; border-color: #005cbf;`.

Получается, что при нажатии и отпускании кнопка «мерцает»: фон и граница меняют цвет при переходах между состояниями `:hover` и `:active`.

Чтобы от этого избавится, задайте этим состояниям одинаковые цвета для фона и границы. Например:

```css
.btn:focus,
.btn:active {
  box-shadow: none !important;
}

.btn-primary:hover,
.btn-primary:active {
  background-color: #0069d9 !important;
  border-color: #0062cc !important;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

---

#### 3) Устраняем мерцание для кнопки без классов

Ели правильно понял доп. вопрос, он уже не про Бутстрап, а про стили, добавленные браузером. Чтобы избавиться от них, задаём собственные.

Если кнопка не должна меняться, чтобы с ней не происходило, проще всего поставить `!important`:

```css
input[type="button"] {
  border-style: solid !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  outline: none !important;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Some Button">
```

Comment: Дополнил вопрос новым кодом. Теперь при наведении на кнопку перестал изменяться(затемняться) цвет фона, она лишь подсвечивается по контуру. Но при нажатии этот эффект остался. Это видно и на вашем примере, если нажать выполнить код и кликнуть на кнопку.

Comment: Бутстрап задаёт `btn-primary` фон и границу: `background-color: #007bff; border-color: #007bff;`. При наведении мыши делает их темнее: `background-color: #0069d9; border-color: #0062cc;`. При нажатии - ещё темнее: `background-color: #0062cc; border-color: #005cbf;`. В своём коде вижу только эти эффекты. Чтобы переопределить их, скопируйте соответствующие строки из [bootstrap.css](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.css) и поменяйте значения свойств.

Comment: @Gleb_Kemarsky спасибо, ваш ответ был очень ценен. Проблема стала очевидна - создайте самый простой <input type="button">. По щелчку он мерцает. Возможно ли это убрать? Чтобы жать по кнопке как по ссылке без всяких эффектов

Comment: @Gleb_Kemarsky дополнил, что я делаю не так? Последний вопрос, больше не буду мучать) И спасибо вам

Comment: У меня bootsrap btn btn-primary выглядит отлично. Но это мой пилотный проект на сервлетах и jsp, поэтому при каждом отправлении формы страница перерисовывается. Код что вы показали в действии отлично выполняет то, что нужно, однако меняет отличное оформление bootstrap на примитивный синеватый цвет, а хотелось бы сохранить bootstrap оформление для зажатой клавиши. В остальном все работает как нужно теперь

Comment: Я запутался, что хотите убрать и что сохранить. Предлагаю вам составить новый вопрос и сделать в нём работающие примеры кода: как было и как получилось. Посмотрите как я отредактировал ваш вопрос, чтобы примеры из него можно было увидеть в действии.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<form>
  <label class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
    Click<input type="submit" style="display:none"/>
  </label>
</form>
```

Comment: тут вообще скнопка скрыта, а я беру класс из коробки и хочу отменить некоторые его атрибуты